# Creating collaborative data flow charts

Tags: asp.net, charts, dataflow-diagram

I need a tool which can be installed on .aspx platform (on a intranet of a company) which can be used to create collaborative data flow chart diagrams (multiple users can edit the diagram by visiting the intranet webpage).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried gliffy? - I've seen it used on intranets before, not sure if it's .net or if you can share it, but I recommend it.

Comment: As I looked through their website I understood this is only for collaborating online (using their servers). I need a solution to store the data flow chart on the intranet servers.

Answer (score -1):

I am not aware of a collaborative diagram program that allows you to store the data on your servers. An on premise solution would probably be prohibitively expensive. These SaaS guys aren't really setup to provide that option. You probably would have to get an open source solution and build it out yourself. The company that I work for (Lucidchart) does have a [flow chart maker](https://www.lucidchart.com) that allows you to lock down the domain so you can't share it with third parties and allows license de-provisioning for someone who leaves the company.

Source: I works for a diagramming company.